UTF-8 String in Springboot app's context-path not working
I am trying to use a UTF-8 String in the context-path of a Springboot app as below in application.properties:
server.servlet.context-path=/सार्वजनिक

.. the app compiles and runs with below console output:
.   ____          _            __ _ _
/\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
'  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
=========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)

2024-04-13T16:29:10.376+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] c.m.s.SaarvajanikApplicationKt           : Starting SaarvajanikApplicationKt using Java 21.0.2 with PID 24064 (D:\*****\saarvajanik\build\classes\kotlin\main started by ManishNandaniya in D:\*****\saarvajanik)
2024-04-13T16:29:10.379+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] c.m.s.SaarvajanikApplicationKt           : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-04-13T16:29:12.287+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-04-13T16:29:12.305+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-04-13T16:29:12.305+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-04-13T16:29:12.313+05:30  WARN 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext   : Failed to create work directory [C:\*****\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8080.719495575958282208\work\Tomcat\localhost\?????????] for context [/?????????]
2024-04-13T16:29:12.386+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/?????????]     : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-04-13T16:29:12.388+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1881 ms
2024-04-13T16:29:12.893+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path '/?????????'
2024-04-13T16:29:12.904+05:30  INFO 24064 --- [saarvajanik] [           main] c.m.s.SaarvajanikApplicationKt           : Started SaarvajanikApplicationKt in 3.05 seconds (process running for 3.627)

but when I try to access the app using the same context-path as localhost:8080\सार्वजनिक, I am getting 404, Not found. When I use normal ASCII characters in (custom) context-path it works fine.
I have tried below config as well in application.properties:
server.servlet.encoding.charset=UTF-8
server.tomcat.uri-encoding=UTF-8
server.servlet.encoding.force=true
server.servlet.container-uri-encoding=UTF-8

but nothing worked so far.
Any help for, how to use a UTF-8 String in Springboot app's context-path, is appreciated.
